# Text difference of scrolling output

Tags: c++, algorithm, text

I have code that is capturing the text from scrolling output and I'm looking for an algorithm (working with C++/Qt) that can tell me which lines are new. **NOTE:** New lines are only ever added to the end.

So on first capture I might have the following:

```
hello world
some more text
hello world
some text
```

And on second capture might have:

```
hello world
some text
yet more text
hello world
```

So I want the algorithm to return that I have two new lines:

```
yet more text
hello world
```

If possible it would be help performance if it could start from the last line and terminate once it reaches an already processed line. But I'm thinking this is probably not possible since there can be duplicate lines.

Comment: You said it yourself, there can be duplicate lines. In fact, all lines can be equal, in which case you could never now if anything new was entered. You should probably better try to handle the addition of each new line as it happens. Also, what if you miss lines, because the user entered more than fits into the buffer?

Comment: How is this scrolling output being captured? I am assuming that for some reason, you are not able to get the total number of lines in the captured output.

Comment: I'm taking screen captures and applying OCR to convert back to text. I've made the scroll area large enough that I won't miss lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well you say its scrolling, and you are using OCR, so could you also capture the size of the scroll widget on the scroll window, and check that along with the lines youve recorded?

Alternatively can you hook a dll into the producer program so you can signal when it outputs a new line? or directly pipe its output into yours?

Comment: Unfortunately no this program has protection against most methods. Its why I'm resorting to OCR

Comment: Also the scrollbar doesn't change. So that doesn't help either

Answer (score 0):

For your special case I would consider a plain basic loop-inside-loop algorithm. I don't think that performance is really an issue (not so much lines, I also consider OCR to be the major part) and therefore the algorithm should be easily readable and robust.

One possible algorithm in pseudo code:

```
numberOfNewLines = 0
while numberOfNewLines <= numberOfTotalLines do
    compare lines 
        [1..numberOfTotalLines-numberOfNewLines] of textNew
        with lines [1+numberOfNewLines..numberOfTotalLines] of textOld
    if identical then exit while
    numberOfNewLines++
end while
```

You can break comparison as soon as one line differs, but still the algorithm is `O(N^2)` in the number of lines.

Then you can output the last `numberOfNewLines` from the end of `textNew`. As mentioned in the comment you can of course not detect some edge cases like "10000 times 'ABC' and then 1 times 'DEF'" where most of the lines 'ABC' will be neglected.

Comment: I was hoping to only OCR each line as required. I have done this for the solution that I have posted. Just not sure how robust it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this against a number of test cases and it works so far:

```
QStringList scrollDiff(const QStringList& oldLines, const QStringList& newLines)
{
    if (oldLines.empty()) {
        return newLines;
    }

    if (oldLines.size() < newLines.size()) {
        return newLines.mid(oldLines.size());
    }

    /*
     * Note: oldLines.size() == newLines.size()
     */
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < oldLines.size() && oldLines[i] == newLines[i]; ++i);

    if (i == oldLines.size()) {
        return QStringList();
    }

    // Remove lines from oldLines that are no longer shown
    int j = oldLines.indexOf(newLines[i]);
    if (j == -1) {
        return newLines;
    }
    QStringList commonLines = oldLines.mid(j - i);

    return newLines.mid(commonLines.size());
}
```